# appending Line Breaks in StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a online RSVP web app using MVC and C#. One of the requirements is to create and send a confirmation email to the person upon verifying that they are on the guest list.

Everything works well but I'm using StringBuilder to build out my email body text. The one think I need is Line Breaks so I can display some text in an address Block style. for example.

```
Dean Forant
Phone: 555-555-5555
Email: email@email.com
```

When I use appendLine("text") The Text appends but the next line appears on the same line in the email

Belows is a sample of the rendered output in the email message

```
Dean Forant: Phone – 555-555-555 Email – email@email.com
```

I've tried adding an additional AppendLine(); between the each line but that gives me a line space which I don't want.

Based on some of the other articles I have read on here, I tried to do  the following:

```
AppendFormat("text{0}",Environment.NewLine);
```

but that seem to have no effect. Meaning, it still show all the lines on one line.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Dean

Comment: can you post a full code example showing what's not working?

Comment: How are you displaying the output? Html doesn't always show line breaks... you would need a `<br>` tag in some cases. If this is the solution, there are probably much better ways to do it though...

Comment: What is the content format of the email? plain text or html?

Comment: This definitely sounds like you are creating a plain text email, but rendering it as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringBuilder's Append() method to add a new line like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("Dean Forant");
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendLine("Phone: 555-555-5555");
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendLine("Email: email@email.com");
```